# Using mysql_fetch_assoc and updating each record

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, rows

Some of my rows have a "," comma as the initial character in the field. So I need to loop through, check if each row has the initial commma, remove it if it does, and update the row.

I am running the following code, which seems to go on an endless loop when the update is called.

When I am just echoing out the result at the end, everything looks fine in the browser. But on execution of the update line below the echo, it seems as if a single datum from the column "Tags" is being populated for every record, instead of just the rows that have the initial commma that I am removing.

Would love help :)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Tags FROM products")
   or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $str = $row['Tags'];
    $initial = substr($str,0,1); 

 if ($initial = ",") {
        $str = (ltrim($str, ','));
    }

    echo "result: " .$str  . "<br/>";
    $result = "UPDATE products SET Tags = '" .$str ."'";
    mysql_query($result);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the particular row id to the one you're making changes to, by using a `WHERE` clause:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Tags FROM products")
   or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $str = $row['Tags'];
    $initial = substr($str,0,1); 

    if ($initial == ",") {
        //  == not =
        $str = (ltrim($str, ','));
    }

    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "result: " .$str  . "<br/>";
    $result = "UPDATE products SET Tags = '$str' WHERE id = $id";
    mysql_query($result);
}
```

By the way, if possible kindly change to the better extension which is mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting an error in the browser -  "Undefined index: id". Is that because the array is associative?

Comment: @Kailas no what i mean by that `$row['id']` is just a placeholder value. i just assumed you have an id. that is the name of the id of that particular table? `$row['product_id']` i guess?

Answer (score 0):

You're if() statement has an error in it. 
You're using one equal:

```
if($initial = ",") {

}
```

Instead of two for actual comparison:

```
if($initial == ",") {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code. Thank you everyone.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ProductID, Tags FROM products")
   or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $str = $row['Tags'];
    $initial = substr($str,0,1); 

    if ($initial == ",") {
        $str = (ltrim($str, ','));

        $id = $row['ProductID'];
        //echo $id . " ";
        //echo $str  . "<br/>";
    $result = "UPDATE products SET Tags = '$str' WHERE ProductID = $id";
       echo $result ."<br>";
       mysql_query($result);
    }
}
```

So grateful for the help. I will update to mysqlli also.